# Setting a Time-Zone breaks Devise Authenthication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm using [ruby-on-rails-5](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-5) with [devise](/questions/tagged/devise) and devise-token-auth.

I did this in my user model and it worked fine:

```
before_create :skip_confirmation!

# Include default devise modules.
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

I was able to create accounts, which got confirmed automatically.
For other stuff I needed to change the timezone of the application by adding the following to my application.rb.

```
config.time_zone = 'Europe/Berlin'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Europe/Berlin'
```

The time zone stuff works as well, but for unknown reasons, creating users stopped. If I create one and try to login, this error occurs:

```
A confirmation email was sent to your account at '...'. You must follow the instructions in the email before your account can be activated
```

In my database after creating an account with the new time zones every timestamp value for the user record was inserted correctly (using the new time zones).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that for some reason the timezone Devise uses to set the `confirmed_at` field on the `users` table is ahead of the 'Europe/Berlin' time zone. So when Devise does the check to see if `confirmed_at` is set to a date/time before the current date/time, it returns false.

**Solution:** Try restarting your server to see if that updates it.

**UPDATE**

I took at look at [`Devise::Models`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb) and I see the following code:

```
  def skip_confirmation!
    self.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc
  end

  def confirmed?
    !!confirmed_at
  end
```

This basically leads me to believe that it is best to set app times in UTC and later convert them using a Gem like [Local Time](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time)

Comment: That didn't help. I restarted the whole server, which also has 'Europe/Berlin' as time zone.